# FadeIn image like Facebook (if not fully loaded, show it fuzzy)

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, image

i am programming a jquery plugin which loads lots of images.

I would prefer to show the picture first fuzzy and if it's fully loaded, in complete.

Facebook is a good example.

How does this technique work?

Comment: I think it might just be progressively loading jpegs?

Comment: This might help: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/12/progressive-image-rendering.html I'm pretty sure that this is done at the image level, rather than javascript level

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the format that the image is saved in.

JPG images normally load (and hence display) from top to bottom. If however they are stored in progressive (also called interlaced) format then they will load the whole image in a grainy format and gradually increase the quality. Facebook save their images in the progressive format.

There are utilities available for converting from the first format into the second. Here is a link to a well known one (ImageMagick): [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)

Comment: ok thanks, i am going to try that

how should i show the image with jquery?
actually i use .load, which would not work i think

Comment: Yeah .load probably won't display the effect because it loads all of the image before it's put in place. You only see the effect if the image is downloaded while it's being rendered. So for example you could add an img tag into the appropriate part of the page.

Comment: It's also worth noting that you don't get the effect if the image is loaded from the browser cache. Only if it's loaded (relatively slowly) over the network. That's why you only see it on Facebook the first time that you load the image.

Answer (score 0):

You just have two images: one of bad quality, and one of good quality and.
When you want to show image, you first set image.src to bad quality image, and then instantly to good image path (setTimeout with 0 delay will work too).

It works, because browser doesn't replace image in img tag until it's fully loaded. Image with bad quality will loaded much faster than good image, so user will first see fuzzy image and fully loaded image when it's loaded.

Example

```
img.src = 'path/to/fuzzyImage.jpg';
setTimeout(function() {
    img.src = 'path/to/fullImage.jpg';
}, 0);
```

Comment: This approach will have the problem of needing two HTTP requests per image. If you have more than one image on the page, this will really reduce performance.

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach is to set width and height on a thumbnail version of the image to full size of the big image, and replace the thumbnail with full image when the large one is loaded. When you set the full size on the thumbnail image, it becomes 'fuzzy' becuase it's interpolated to a larger size by the browser.